# Categorical Data evaluation in Python with get_dummies

Tags: python, dataframe, categorical-data

I want to evaluate categorical data in Python with a decision tree. I want to use the categorical data and use binning to create categorical labels. Do I have to?
The problem is that `get_dummies` returns a dataframe with a different length then the values that were given. It is two rows shorter than the original data.
Previously I tried to use the labelencode, but didn't get it done. I tried the get_dummies form pandas which seamed more easily to me.

I checked the reference for the `get_dummies` function and searched for the problem but could not find why the length is shorter.

Doing the binning:

```
est = bine(n_bins=50, encode='ordinal', strategy='kmeans')
cat_labels = est.fit_transform(np.array(quant_labels).reshape(-1, 1))
```

Extact the cateorical data (do I have to?):

```
category = rd.select_dtypes(exclude=['number']).astype("category")
category = category.replace(math.nan, "None")
category = category.replace(0, "None")
```

Prepare the split:

```
one_hot_features = pd.get_dummies(category[1:-1])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(one_hot_features, cat_labels, test_size = 0.6, random_state = None)
```

The Error is:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent number of samples: [1458, 1460]
```

The correct size of samples is 1460. The `one_hot` encoded is two samples short. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

When you are encoding your data you use `category[1:-1]`. This will encode all the elements from the second to the second to last element.

**Explanation:**

1) Indexes are zero based so 1 is the index of the second item.
2) Index of -1 means the second to last element.

**Solution:**
Change your line to `one_hot_features = pd.get_dummies(category[:])`